# Webpack Bundle Analyzer Is Not Working For Jhipster Angular Application

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I am using jhipster gateway application as a gateway for micro services.

To analyze my webpack bundle I am trying below approach

Ran `npm install -g webpack-bundle-analyzer`

In your Angular app, run `ng build --stats-json`

here I am getting an error like below

```
Cannot determine project or target for command.
Error: Cannot determine project or target for command.
    at BuildCommand.initialize (C:\Rk\gateway\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:122:23)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`webpack-bundle-analyzer` comes preconfigured for JHipster apps for the `prod` build. You can find its config in [webpack.prod.js](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/942cf2d5ff424dd4a6bcb2112ea8952f477700b7/webpack/webpack.prod.js#L132-L137).

To view the output, run `npm run webpack:prod` and open `target/classes/stats.html` (or in `build` instead of `target` for gradle)